# Why a new user was created seemingly to run gvfsd-admin daemon?

Tags: permissions, user-management

[image]

A new user was created seemingly to run gvfsd-admin daemon.  The new user is called dachsroot.
This happened after I installed many astronomy packages into my ubuntu 22.04.
it is not clear what triggered it.

Another possible source was the LM studio.

I had to run the AppImage

LM+Studio-0.2.6-linux-beta-v7.AppImage

Here is the groups dachsgroup belong to:

id dachsroot

uid=1001(dachsroot) gid=1003(gavo) groups=1003(gavo)

Is this legit?  Why would my computer run gvfsd-admin now?  What changed?
Does anyone have the same problem?

Thanks,

MP

Answer (score 0):

These are the gavo libraries installed.  So it seems it has to do with gavodachs2-server.  I might have installed a astrophysics server in my computer without knowing.

apt search gavo
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
gavodachs2-server/jammy,jammy,now 2.5.3+dfsg-1 all [installed,automatic]
server package of the Virtual Observatory data center suite

python3-gavo/jammy,jammy,now 2.5.3+dfsg-1 all [installed,automatic]
Virtual Observatory data center publishing suite

python3-gavo-stc/jammy,jammy,now 2.5.3+dfsg-1 all [installed,automatic]
IVOA Space-Time-Coordinate (STC) library

python3-gavo-utils/jammy,jammy,now 2.5.3+dfsg-1 all [installed,automatic]
support library for the Virtual Observatory

python3-gavo-votable/jammy,jammy,now 2.5.3+dfsg-1 all [installed,automatic]
library for the reading and writing of VOTables

Please feel free to comment on the server or hit me in the head...:) both would help.